# Updating pair of jquery toggle functions from .live not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a pair of functions used to toggle the state of a password field between obfuscated and plain text. Both functions are triggered by clicking on a lock icon, and listen for a click event on a specific class. Clicking the lock icon does 3 things:

1. Toggle state of password field
2. Toggle class of lock icon
3. Toggle lock icon image from open to closed

   ```
   $(".show-plain").live("click", function()
   {
   //do toggling

   //toggle class

   //toggle icon
   }

   $(".show-hidden").live("click", function()
   {
   //do toggling

   //toggle class

   //toggle icon
   }
   ```

I am in the process of moving away from the deprecated .live(), but am seeing some strange results in upgrading it. Changing the event listener to either of the following IS successful...

```
    $(document).on("click", ".show-hidden", function()
```

or

```
    $(".show-hidden").click(function()
```

However, if I update both functions to use either of these options, only the first function works. The second doesn't seem to fire at all and there is no error information in the browser console. If I leave one using .live() and use either of the above methods for the other function, both functions seem to trigger immediately (not noticeable unless I put in diagnostic alert messages).

Before spending more time trying to collapse both functions into a single toggle feature, I'm looking for information about why this is happening and how to avoid it, as .live() still seems to be functional but is providing validation errors.

Comment: The `$(document).on("click", ".show-hidden", function()` version should be working fine. The other version will not work on elements added some time after that line of code runs. Can you clarify your question a bit as far as what works and what doesn't? it seems quite a bit unclear.

Comment: Also if you are having issues please provide a runnable [mcve] that reproduces them

Comment: I'd like to see an actual code example because it's very hard to tell what's happening here. A suggestion though, from a troubleshooting standpoint, would be to try out using `.on` with events as well as different _namespaces_ -  a.e. `.on("click.nameSpace", ...)` and 
 `.on("click.differentNameSpace", ...)` to see if you get a different result.